# dos or linux multiline search and multiline replace / add

Tags: linux, batch-file, sed, awk

I'm trying to find a multiline pattern within a file and either add 2 line after it or replace it.

This is what the input and output should look like.

**INPUT**

```
$ DATE: Fri Apr 20 16:36:56 2012
$---------------------------$
$ FILE MANAGEMENT SECTION   $
$---------------------------$
$
$---------------------------$
$ EXECUTIVE CONTROL SECTION $
$---------------------------$
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ DATE: Fri Apr 20 16:36:56 2012
$---------------------------$
$ FILE MANAGEMENT SECTION   $
$---------------------------$
$
BLKABLA
$
$---------------------------$
$ EXECUTIVE CONTROL SECTION $
$---------------------------$
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '1;/^\$$/{print "BLKABLA\n$"}' file
```

One way to do it just the first time the pattern is seen:

```
awk '1;/^\$$/ && !done{print "BLKABLA\n$"; done=1}' file
```

Comment: Thanks it works well but I have more than one occurrence.  How to limit it to the first one?

Comment: if this is the answer you were looking for, please indicate that by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

As this is Linux, you probably have GNU sed. Try:

```
sed -e '/^\$ FILE MANAGEMENT SECTION   \$$/,+2{/^\$-\+\$/,+1{/^\$$/afoo\
$
}
}' input
```

It matches on the three regexps

```
^\$ FILE MANAGEMENT SECTION   \$$
^\$-\+\$$
^\$$
```

Then appends

```
foo
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the holding buffer and read the whole file into it first and then apply the regular expression across the whole file. I described the solution already here - [multiline sed using backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807033/multiline-sed-using-backreferences)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^$ FILE MANAGEMENT SECTION   $$/!b;n;/^$--*$$/a$\nBLKABLA' file
```

or

```
sed '/^$ FILE MANAGEMENT SECTION   $$/!b;n;$!N;/^$--*$\n$$/aBLKABLA\n$' file
```